# Does 星月夜 mean Starry Night?

Tags: translation, kanji

If I am not wrong, the literal translation should be star moon night, right? How does it translate to Starry Night then? Isn't the `月` character useless in that case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a tricky word, but the 月 doesn't stand for the real moon.

[**星月夜**](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/203879/meaning/m0u/)

> **１** 晴れて星の光が月のように明るい夜。
>   *(A clear night where stars shine as bright as the moon.)*

Thus the "literal" translation would be "star-moon night" and not "star and moon night".